# Images (IMG) are not aligning when testing responsiveness in Chrome DevTools

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if someone can help me out with the following.  The first image shows the table I created when displayed on a desktop, which looks good.

However, when I run Chrome DevTools to check the responsiveness, the second image below shows what it looks like, which is not what I like.  I have provided a jsfiddle link of it: https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/4zLwoehm/12/

This was done with Bootstrap.  Can somebody tell me how I can get the circles to align perfectly, just like in the first image?  Any help is appreciated. I have already tried ***class="img-responsiveness"*** in the tables div, but that did not work.

[image]

[image]

```
<div style="width: auto; text-align: center">
   <div class="row">
       <table style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
         <td style="width: 40%; border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ;background-color: floralwhite"><h3>Text here</h3></td>
          <td style="width: 10%; border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ; border-left-color: floralwhite; background-color: floralwhite; text-align:left">
          <i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size:24px; color:red; margin-left:15px;"></i>
          </td>
            <td style="height: 100px; width: 30%; border-left: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid; border-left-color: gray;border-right-color: gray;border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ;background-color: floralwhite">
               <div style="top: 0px">
                  <label>Accessorial Adjustment Refund</label>
               </div>
               <br />
                 <div style="left: 20%; position: relative">
                     <div class="col-lg-2">
                       <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/0gray.png" id="@iconId1" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 0, 1, 0)" />
                       <text>0%</text>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
                        <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/50gray.png" id="@iconId2" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 1, 2, 0)" />
                        <text style="text-align: center">50%</text>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-2" style="margin-left: 10px">
                       <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/100gray.png" id="@iconId3" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 2, 3, 0)" />
                       <text style="text-align: center">100%</text>
                     </div>  
                 </div>
             </td>
             <td style=" border-top: 1px solid;  border-top-color: gray ;border-right-color: floralwhite; border-left-color: floralwhite; background-color: floralwhite">
                <div style="top: 0px">
                  <label>Invoice</label>
                </div>  
                  <text style="color: gray">
                     $123.00
                 </text>
             </td>
   </table>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You might get a better response if you fix your indentation and reduce the code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Probably due to your use of center alignment

Comment: Add the row class to the div containing the col-lg-2 divs

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `BS4` classes in right way nothing else compare your code and my code you can understand easily what the problem was?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: auto; text-align: center">
      <div class="row">
        <table style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 40%; border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ;background-color: floralwhite">
              <h3>Text here</h3>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 10%; border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ; border-left-color: floralwhite; background-color: floralwhite; text-align:left">
              <i class="fas fa-circle" style="font-size:24px; color:red; margin-left:15px;"></i>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 100px; width: 30%; border-left: 1px solid; border-right: 1px solid; border-left-color: gray;border-right-color: gray;border-top: 1px solid; border-top-color: gray ;background-color: floralwhite">
              <div style="top: 0px">
                <label>Accessorial Adjustment Refund</label>
              </div>
              <br/>
              <div class="form-row m-0">
                <div class="col-lg-2 ml-auto">
                  <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/0gray.png" id="@iconId1" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 0, 1, 0)" />
                  <text class="text-center d-lg-block">0%</text>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                  <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/50gray.png" id="@iconId2" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 1, 2, 0)" />
                  <text class="text-center d-lg-block">50%</text>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 mr-auto">
                  <img src="~/Content/images/AuditingIcons/100gray.png" id="@iconId3" onclick="updateAudit(@d, 2, 3, 0)" />
                  <text class="text-center d-lg-block">100%</text>
                </div>  
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style=" border-top: 1px solid;  border-top-color: gray ;border-right-color: floralwhite; border-left-color: floralwhite; background-color: floralwhite">
              <div style="top: 0px">
                <label>Invoice</label>
              </div>  
              <text style="color: gray">$123.00</text>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

**You just need to add width or min width to  that equal to the 100% width.. **

the problem you are facing is only because the width of 0%, 50% and 100% are different.